# Kotlin - same class, different internal class

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have Kotlin object

```
object LocalizationHelper {

    var lang: String = ""
        get() = MyApi.getCurrentLanguage()

    fun initLanguage() {
        val preferredLanguage = Locale.getDefault().language.toLowerCase()
        lang = if (MyApi.setSupportedLanguage(preferredLanguage)) preferredLanguage else "en"
    }
    //bunch of other methods
}
```

Is there a way, how to have the same class, but with `MyApi2` without the duplicate code of entire `LocalizationHelper`?

The reason is that I am using this helper class in the main application with `MyApi` and for widget, I need simplified `MyApi2`. However, 90% of time, I use it with `MyApi`.

I have thought, that something like generic object with `T` that defaults to `MyApi` would be nice, but I am not sure, how or if it can be achived (note: I am mainly C++ programmer, where this is possible).

```
object LocalizationHelper<T> {

    var lang: String = ""
        get() = T.getCurrentLanguage()

    fun initLanguage() {
        val preferredLanguage = Locale.getDefault().language.toLowerCase()
        lang = if (T.setSupportedLanguage(preferredLanguage)) preferredLanguage else "en"
    }
    //bunch of other methods
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract an interface of `MyApi` and `MyApi2`:

```
interface Api {
    fun getCurrentLanguage(): String
    fun setSupportedLanguage(language: String): Boolean
}

object MyApi : Api {
    override fun getCurrentLanguage() = "en"

    override fun setSupportedLanguage(language: String) = true
}

object MyApi2 : Api {
    override fun getCurrentLanguage() = "de"

    override fun setSupportedLanguage(language: String) = true
}
```

then you can move common behavior of `LocalizationHelper` to abstract parent:

```
abstract class LocalizationHelperAbstract(private val api: Api) {
    var lang: String = ""
        get() = api.getCurrentLanguage()

    fun initLanguage() {
        val preferredLanguage = Locale.getDefault().language.toLowerCase()
        lang = if (api.setSupportedLanguage(preferredLanguage)) preferredLanguage else "en"
    }
    //bunch of other methods
}
```

and instatiate objects with appropriate api:

```
object LocalizationHelper : LocalizationHelperAbstract(MyApi)

object LocalizationHelper2 : LocalizationHelperAbstract(MyApi2)
```